# To repair boot or not to repair boot

Tags: boot, uefi, asus

Sorry, yet another n00b with dual boot issues.

I installed Ubuntu on an Asus X401a. The installation never found the existing OS (Windows 7) but after a learning curve, I made it through, by making my own partitions and following other advice in Ubuntu's main UEFI documentation.

Now, when I boot up, I get grub, and from there I can select Ubuntu or it will boot up automatically, or I can go to "system setup" (the UEFI equivalent of BIOS menu, I guess). But there is no Windows 7 choice.

I can press "C", type "exit" and then it boots straight into Windows. This is really fine.

But I'm here to learn, after all, and it seems to me I'm not really finished unless Windows 7 is one of my options in the grub menu. Should I leave well enough alone or forge ahead with your sage guidance?

For your viewing pleasure, I made a boot-repair-disk thingie but I didn't actually ask the program to repair anything, having seen many forum posts from n00bs like myself do it wrong and make things worse. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6126199/

Thanks for reading!

Comment: "I tried "grub-probe" mentioned in the other post, and got "grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1.  Check your device.map."

Comment: Rod, are you the developer of REfind? I went ahead and tried it and it works great! I would, however, like to change it. I'll post a new question related to it

Comment: Yes, I'm rEFInd's developer. I've answered [your other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/348463/refind-configuration-change-boot-order-and-default-boot/348543#348543) separately.