# Mac stuck in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard

I have installed Ubuntu on my Mac, but now it boots into Ubuntu by default. I have paired my magic keyboard to ubuntu, and apparently it doesnt work if i'm no in ubuntu, so holding down the option key while booting up doesn't work.  I dont have any usb keyboards. I want to get back to macOS, so can you please help me?
GRUB or rEFInd wouldn't work anyway since when it goes into the ubuntu desktop is the only time it'll recognize the keyboard.

Comment: Try holding down the Option key when powering it on before the boot starts.  If that doesn't work, you will have to get a USB keyboard to make it work.  There is nothing else that we could do beyond that.

Comment: will it be okay for me to delete the ubuntu patition via the files app on the ubuntu install disk?

Comment: I guess you could try that, but it will probably boot to a `grub>` prompt since grub itself will be looking for the Ubuntu partition that contains libraries that it needs.  Whether you install rEFInd, Mac OS X or Ubuntu, each will install their own bootloader.

Comment: I tried rEFInd, and when I did, I saw that Ubuntu was the first OS on the left, and was the one that was highlighted.  Is there a way to make the primary and first partition the macOS one?  Also, I have a G502 mouse.  I could remap the buttons to alt, forward, and back.

Comment: I am not using rEFInd at the moment because my Macbook is only running Mac OS at the this time, but if you look here https://askubuntu.com/a/348543/231142 looks like that is where you can set the default OS boot for rEFInd.