# Dual Boot Ubuntu Windows 10 installation problem on Dynabook L50-G

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have a Dynabook L50-G (ex Toshiba) with Insyde BIOS version 2.20
I disabled secure boot and hibernation,
tried the bcdedit command,

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

tried setting grubx64.efi instead of bootmgfw.efi,
tried boot-repair and
even tried the rEFInd program...
Still no dualboot!! I can only boot to Windows 10 :'(

I also attempted to tinker with the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file with the code

```
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)' --class windows --class os 

$menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-CCBD-2C47' {
   insmod part_gpt
   insmod fat
   if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  CCBD-2C47
   else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root CCBD-2C47
   fi
   chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw-win.efi
}
```

Boot-Info

```
boot-info-4ppa200                                              [20220627_1555]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /EFI/refind/refind.conf /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
                       /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64_old.efi
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi
                       /efi/refind/refind_x64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Boot/refind/refind_x64.efi
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw_new.efi
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
                       /efi/refind/drivers_x64/ext4_x64.efi
                       /efi/toshiba/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
                       /efi/toshiba/Boot/bootmgfw_new.efi
                       /efi/toshiba/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/boot/bootx64.efi /efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi
                       /efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot_noprompt.efi /bootmgr
                       /boot/bcd

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub
                       /boot/refind_linux.conf

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: FAT16
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on nvme0n1p6
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] GP108M [GeForce MX250] from Intel Corporation NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 2.20(2.32) from Insyde
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled - SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0007,2004,2005,2001,2003
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9b0995a4-a0ed-44df-8be8-b7bc9a5b2d99,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* EFI Hard Drive (21SPD4OEQGK3-KBG40ZNV256G TOSHIBA MEMORY)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,8C-E3-8E-04-01-E9-57-A2)/HD(5,GPT,1f83bf57-e663-4110-97f6-51bd07eb9edc,0x1c3d128f,0x1922000)RC
Boot0002* Linpus lite    HD(1,GPT,c5e6ff18-3cf2-4311-9789-6d5ce133e9c7,0x800,0x75001f)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0003* EFI PXE 0 for IPv4 (7C-D3-0A-94-89-D0)     PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(7cd30a9489d0,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0004* EFI PXE 0 for IPv6 (7C-D3-0A-94-89-D0)     PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(7cd30a9489d0,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0006* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9b0995a4-a0ed-44df-8be8-b7bc9a5b2d99,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0007* Windows Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,9b0995a4-a0ed-44df-8be8-b7bc9a5b2d99,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0008* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9b0995a4-a0ed-44df-8be8-b7bc9a5b2d99,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0009* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9b0995a4-a0ed-44df-8be8-b7bc9a5b2d99,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot000A* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9b0995a4-a0ed-44df-8be8-b7bc9a5b2d99,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot000B* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9b0995a4-a0ed-44df-8be8-b7bc9a5b2d99,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot000C* rEFInd Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,9b0995a4-a0ed-44df-8be8-b7bc9a5b2d99,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2003* EFI Network    RC
Boot2004* HDD1/SSD1    RC
Boot2005* HDD2/SSD2    RC

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
fff7eb4219a93fa99b0132e0a57842e9   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64_old.efi
c152ec201c37b6e97bbc2207e49d1271   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
045d60dbc29e0a43a324985d8b47d878   nvme0n1p1/refind/refind_x64.efi
f62c28d9b477b6a1a7b1c991b2b6637d   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
fff7eb4219a93fa99b0132e0a57842e9   nvme0n1p1/Boot/refind/refind_x64.efi
0a0bd0238df6ae19e55d14e17f51b68b   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
f62c28d9b477b6a1a7b1c991b2b6637d   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw_new.efi
77f54a5c9cee13656d204d0bd70c388f   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
0f5c4cda98b4371d09120e2b370d46e2   nvme0n1p1/refind/drivers_x64/ext4_x64.efi
4f0248591a11d5432380ba65f683879b   nvme0n1p1/toshiba/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
f62c28d9b477b6a1a7b1c991b2b6637d   nvme0n1p1/toshiba/Boot/bootmgfw_new.efi
1feb5f9427494e6f598603caa3af7d99   nvme0n1p1/toshiba/Boot/bootmgr.efi
ae8af199ef80311f9cee9de104a15496   nvme0n1p5/boot/bootx64.efi
1309af23db7b4cdd16bb29b41d6975e5   nvme0n1p5/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi
ba914e4bb811a1b27220f020d2672167   nvme0n1p5/microsoft/boot/cdboot_noprompt.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1    : is-GPT,    no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,     not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda    : notGPT,    no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,     not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    not-far
nvme0n1p3    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    farbios
nvme0n1p4    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    farbios
nvme0n1p5    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    farbios
nvme0n1p6    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,    grub2,    grub-install,    grubenv-ok,    update-grub,    farbios
sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1    : is---ESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    haswinload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    recovery-or-hidden,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    recovery-or-hidden,    bootmgr,    is-winboot
nvme0n1p6    : isnotESP,    fstab-has-goodEFI,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6    : not--sepboot,    with-boot,    fstab-without-boot,    not-sep-usr,    with--usr,    fstab-without-usr,    std-grub.d,    nvme0n1
sda1    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xba7eb3d5
      Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Disk nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: E61D7638-1DDD-48FD-A8F6-1F2BF447422D
              Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    567296 347040398 346473103 165.2G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 471736975 473764494   2027520   990M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 473764495 500118158  26353664  12.6G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p6 347041792 471736319 124694528  59.5G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 3.66 GiB, 3926949888 bytes, 7669824 sectors
Disk identifier: FE0081E0-DEE3-4571-91FF-58FC125F4D85
      Start     End Sectors  Size Type
sdb1   2048 7669790 7667743  3.7G Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1:;
1:1049kB:1000GB:1000GB:ntfs::;
sdb:3927MB:scsi:512:512:gpt:TOSHIBA TransMemory:;
1:1049kB:3927MB:3926MB:fat16:Microsoft Basic Data:msftdata;
nvme0n1:256GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:KBG40ZNV256G TOSHIBA MEMORY:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:178GB:177GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
6:178GB:242GB:63.8GB:ext4::;
4:242GB:243GB:1038MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
5:243GB:256GB:13.5GB:fat32:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
└─sda1      ntfs     B0BA4BACBA4B6E42                     ba7eb3d5-01                                      
sdb                                                                                                        
└─sdb1      vfat     FADC-A194                            c5e6ff18-3cf2-4311-9789-6d5ce133e9c7 UBUNTU 22_0 Microsoft Basic Data
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     221C-7F46                            9b0995a4-a0ed-44df-8be8-b7bc9a5b2d99 ESP         EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               9bedfea6-d1cc-481a-bf3c-826479f3de06             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     385A1D245A1CE084                     47e919a7-2c6e-4543-bd78-71fbcd5379ff TIH0553000A Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     C48EF6BB8EF6A4D8                     4a5369d0-4f6f-48b3-8988-1e7ae6d05dac WinRE       Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p5 vfat     86F8-C8B7                            1f83bf57-e663-4110-97f6-51bd07eb9edc HDDR        Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p6 ext4     f63d3ccb-6b00-4ed8-8f3c-16f04f76a0ff 65cb8c37-7472-4433-87a0-be1fcb38aa6c             

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1         187.5M  27% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3         116.4G  30% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4         499.2M  50% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5         994.7M  92% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p6          43.8G  20% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
/dev/sda1              469.8G  50% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sdb1              215.2M  94% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1         vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p5         vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p6         ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda1              fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

================= nvme0n1p1/EFI/refind/refind.conf (filtered) ==================

timeout 20
use_nvram false
menuentry Linux {
    icon EFI/refind/icons/os_linux.png
    volume 904404F8-B481-440C-A1E3-11A5A954E601
    loader bzImage-3.3.0-rc7
    initrd initrd-3.3.0.img
    options "ro root=UUID=5f96cafa-e0a7-4057-b18f-fa709db5b837"
    disabled
}
menuentry "Arch Linux" {
    icon     /EFI/refind/icons/os_arch.png
    volume   "Arch Linux"
    loader   /boot/vmlinuz-linux
    initrd   /boot/initramfs-linux.img
    options  "root=PARTUUID=5028fa50-0079-4c40-b240-abfaf28693ea rw add_efi_memmap"
    submenuentry "Boot using fallback initramfs" {
        initrd /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
    }
    submenuentry "Boot to terminal" {
        add_options "systemd.unit=multi-user.target"
    }
    disabled
}
menuentry Ubuntu {
    loader /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
    icon /EFI/refind/icons/os_linux.png
    disabled
}
menuentry "ELILO" {
    loader \EFI\elilo\elilo.efi
    disabled
}
menuentry "Windows 7" {
    loader \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
    disabled
}
menuentry "Windows via shell script" {
    icon \EFI\refind\icons\os_win.png
    loader \EFI\tools\shell.efi
    options "fs0:\EFI\tools\launch_windows.nsh"
    disabled
}
menuentry "My macOS" {
    icon \EFI\refind\icons\os_mac.png
    volume "macOS boot"
    loader \System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi
    disabled
}
menuentry "macOS via BootNext" {
    icon /EFI/refind/icons/os_mac.png
    firmware_bootnum 80
    disabled
}

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid f63d3ccb-6b00-4ed8-8f3c-16f04f76a0ff root
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p6/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   f63d3ccb-6b00-4ed8-8f3c-16f04f76a0ff
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-39-generic   f63d3ccb-6b00-4ed8-8f3c-16f04f76a0ff
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-25-generic   f63d3ccb-6b00-4ed8-8f3c-16f04f76a0ff
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-221C-7F46
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p6/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=f63d3ccb-6b00-4ed8-8f3c-16f04f76a0ff /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=221C-7F46  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p6/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p6/boot/refind_linux.conf (filtered) ==================

"Boot with standard options"  "root=UUID=f63d3ccb-6b00-4ed8-8f3c-16f04f76a0ff ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7"
"Boot to single-user mode"    "root=UUID=f63d3ccb-6b00-4ed8-8f3c-16f04f76a0ff ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7 single"
"Boot with minimal options"   "ro root=/dev/nvme0n1p6"

================= nvme0n1p6: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 213.658325195 = 229.413879808  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 174.695869446 = 187.578261504  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 170.617733002 = 183.199395840  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-25-generic                 1
 174.695869446 = 187.578261504  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic                 1
 170.617733002 = 183.199395840  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 204.423366547 = 219.497918464  boot/initrd.img                                1
 174.454189301 = 187.318759424  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic              1
 204.423366547 = 219.497918464  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic              1
 174.454189301 = 187.318759424  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

=================== nvme0n1p6: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15 21:50 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 15 21:50 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Apr 15 21:50 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15 21:50 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15 21:50 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 19 13:21 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jun 23 10:36 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15 21:50 41_custom

======================== nvme0n1p6/etc/grub.d/35_fwupd =========================

#! /bin/sh
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
set -e
[ -d ${pkgdatadir:?} ]
# shellcheck source=/dev/null
. "$pkgdatadir/grub-mkconfig_lib"
if [ -f /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf ] &&
   ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/fwupd-*-0abba7dc-e516-4167-bbf5-4d9d1c739416 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
      . /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf
      if [ "${EFI_PATH}" != "" ] && [ "${ESP}" != "" ]; then
      echo "Adding Linux Firmware Updater entry" >&2
cat << EOF
menuentry 'Linux Firmware Updater' \$menuentry_id_option 'fwupd' {
EOF
      ${grub_probe:?}
      prepare_grub_to_access_device '`${grub_probe} --target=device \${ESP}` | sed -e "s/^/\t/"'
cat << EOF
    chainloader ${EFI_PATH}
}
EOF
      fi
fi

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p6,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)
```

Comment: You do not show any file in ESP with this name? `chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw-win.efi` You have bootmfg.efi and bootmfg_new.efi.  Is the _new from rEFInd or did you just copy it?  Grub only boots working Windows. That means Windows must have fast startup or hibernation off, and Windows may turn it back on with upates. Also Windows cannot need chkdsk for grub to boot it. You may be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI to make repairs or changes in settings.

Comment: I ve tried all listed propositions and no result 
thx @karel

Comment: The final solution I ve found is to reinstall rEFInd..
[rEFInd installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348463/refind-configuration-change-boot-order-and-default-boot)

Answer (score 0):

no bootmgfw-win.efi file,
the _new is mine used as backup,
I ve desactivated both fast startup and hibernation,
the tree schema of /boot/efi/EFI/

```
├── Boot
│   ├── banners
│   │   ├── refind_banner-alpha.png
│   │   ├── refind_banner.png
│   │   └── refind_banner.svg
│   ├── bkpbootx64.efi
│   ├── bootx64.efi
│   ├── bootx64_old.efi
│   ├── fbx64.efi
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── mmx64.efi
│   ├── refind
│   │   ├── drivers_x64
│   │   │   ├── btrfs_x64.efi
│   │   │   ├── ext2_x64.efi
│   │   │   ├── ext4_x64.efi
│   │   │   ├── hfs_x64.efi
│   │   │   ├── iso9660_x64.efi
│   │   │   └── reiserfs_x64.efi
│   │   ├── icons
│   │   ├── refind.conf-sample
│   │   ├── refind_x64.efi
│   │   └── tools_x64
│   │       └── gptsync_x64.efi
│   └── refind-install
├── Microsoft
│   ├── Boot
│   │   ├── BCD
│   │   ├── BCD.LOG
│   │   ├── BCD.LOG1
│   │   ├── BCD.LOG2
│   │   ├── bg-BG
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi
│   │   ├── bootmgfw_new.efi
│   │   ├── bootmgr.efi
│   │   ├── BOOTSTAT.DAT
│   │   ├── boot.stl
│   └── Recovery
│       ├── BCD
│       ├── BCD.LOG
│       ├── BCD.LOG1
│       └── BCD.LOG2
├── refind
│   ├── BOOT.CSV
│   ├── drivers_x64
│   │   └── ext4_x64.efi
│   ├── icons
│   ├── refind.conf
│   ├── refind_x64.efi
│   └── vars
│       └── PreviousBoot
├── tools
├── toshiba
│   ├── Boot
│   │   ├── BCD
│   │   ├── BCD.LOG
│   │   ├── BCD.LOG1
│   │   ├── BCD.LOG2
│   │   ├── bg-BG
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi
│   │   ├── bootmgfw_new.efi
│   │   ├── bootmgr.efi
│   │   ├── boot.sdi
│   │   ├── BOOTSTAT.DAT
│   │   ├── boot.stl
│   └── Recovery
│       ├── BCD
│       ├── BCD.LOG
│       ├── BCD.LOG1
│       └── BCD.LOG2
├── ubuntu
│   ├── BOOTX64.CSV
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   ├── grubx64.efi
│   ├── mmx64.efi
│   └── shimx64.efi
└── UpdateCapsule
```